# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' with $_GET[] in if { }

Tags: php, if-statement, get, parse-error

I have the following php-code that I don't seem to be able to get working:

```
<?php
    if($_GET['sizex'] == null) { 
        $sizex = 200; 
    } else { 
        $sizex = $_GET['sizex']; // This is the problematic line
    }
?>
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in test.php on line 6
```

I have found out that the $_GET[] causes this, because if I replace it with anything else like *$sizex = 1*, it works fine. Is there some typo which I cant see, or is there something special about $_GET that I don't know?

var_dump($_GET):

```
array(1) {
  ["sizex"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: Please do var_dump($_GET); and post it here for more reference.

Comment: Was the question that the error happen when he leave the brakets empty? $_GET[]

Comment: @Aziz http://pastebin.com/77Skk1tS

Comment: @Stony no, I just shortened it on the title

Comment: you have something else after `;`, clear the white-spaces will work

Comment: Is this the full code? Check the code if there is error in any other line

Comment: @ajreal You can create an answer if you want, so I can set it as accepted

Comment: I have the same problem: (isset($_GET['kmscategory'])) If I remove $_GET it clears the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine. There is no syntax error there. Probably you have some weird invisible characters. Try to clear all newlines and then insert them back.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me, any case checking GET/POST existing with `isset()/empty()` always good

```
<?
   $sizex = isset($_GET['sizex']) ? $_GET['sizex'] : 200; 
?>
```